# How to split woocommerce cart page based on product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Thanks you for your help. I have a very unique requirement for woocommerce cart page. What i want is to split products based on categories. For example:

Category name 1:
product 1
product 2
product 3

Category name 2:
product 1
product 2
product 3

Assumptions: Each product is assigned a single category, so i want to pull all the categories and display products which is in that category.

I have tried using the following code but it display all the categories.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Cart Page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>
<style>
table {
    position: relative;
}
form.woocommerce-cart-form {
    font-size: 0;
}
td.aa {
    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    border: 0 !IMPORTANT;
    padding: 4px !IMPORTANT;
    font-size: 23px !important;
    background: #28d18b;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: none !Important;
}    
</style>
<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

 <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <th class="product-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <th class="product-subtotal"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>


<?php
  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
         'orderby'      => 'name',
         'show_count'   => '0',
         'pad_counts'   => '0',
         'hide_empty'   => '0'
  );
 $cats = get_categories( $args );
 
 
 foreach ($cats as $cat) {
      $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
echo "<tr>";
     
echo "<td class='aa'>";

   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

 if ( has_term( $category_id, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
      echo $cat->name ;
    $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        

 
    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
     $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

     ?>
     <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

      <td class="product-remove">
       <?php
        echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
         'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
         sprintf(
          '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
          esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
          esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
          esc_attr( $product_id ),
          esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
         ),
         $cart_item_key
        );
       ?>
      </td>

      <td class="product-thumbnail">
      <?php
      $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

      if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
       echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
      } else {
       printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
      }
      ?>
      </td>

      <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
      <?php
      if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
       echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
      } else {
       echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
      }

      do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

      // Meta data.
      echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

      // Backorder notification.
      if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
       echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
      }
      ?>
      </td>

      <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
       <?php
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
       ?>
      </td>

      <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
      <?php
      if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
       $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
      } else {
       $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
        array(
         'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
         'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
         'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
         'min_value'    => '0',
         'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
        ),
        $_product,
        false
       );
      }

      echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
      ?>
      </td>

      <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
       <?php
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
       ?>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <?php
    }

       }
       
   }
 
    echo "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";

 } 
 
   ?>

   </tbody>
</table>


   
<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>

   <tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="actions">

     <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
      <div class="coupon">
       <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
       <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
      </div>
     <?php } ?>

     <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

     <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

     <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
    </td>
   </tr>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals' ); ?>

<div class="cart-collaterals">
 <?php
  /**
   * Cart collaterals hook.
   *
   * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
   * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
   */
  do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
 ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```

Comment: This is working but i think it is not the right solution of what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `cart.php` template first, after then just replace table `<tbody></tbody>` section with follows -

```
<tbody>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

                        <?php
                        $cat_wisw_pros = array();
                        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
                            $cat_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
                            foreach ( $cat_ids as $id ) {
                                $cat_wisw_pros[$id][$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
                            }
                        }
                        ksort( $cat_wisw_pros ); // Cat ID wise sort
                        $grouped_cart_items = array();
                        foreach ( $cat_wisw_pros as $cat_id => $cart_items ) {
                            $term = get_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat' );
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6" class=""><strong><?php echo $term->name; ?></strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php 
                            foreach ( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                                if( !array_key_exists( $cart_item_key, $grouped_cart_items ) ) {
                                    $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                        <td class="product-remove">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                    'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                    sprintf(
                                        '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                        esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                        esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                    ),
                                    $cart_item_key
                                );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <?php
                        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        } else {
                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                        } else {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
                        }

                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        // Meta data.
                        echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

                        // Backorder notification.
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                            $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                        } else {
                            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                                array(
                                    'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                    'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                    'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                    'min_value'    => '0',
                                    'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                                ),
                                $_product,
                                false
                            );
                        }

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                    <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                        <div class="coupon">
                            <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank, but it is not what i want. Have you read my question. I am not sorting based on categories, my objective is to display category name and list products under category name on the cart. In simple words the products that belongs to a specific category should appear under that category name.

Comment: Then you have to override `cart.php` template first. And after then just replace the table `<tbody></tbody>` section with above. I update my codes. Please replace the above.

Comment: Yes it was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to have the table for each category? like description, price, quantity etc (currently it is appearing once on the top) but i want it to appear under each category name.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Just you have to re-structure overridden cart.php template. You can include table with headers within `foreach ( $cat_wisw_pros as $cat_id => $cart_items ) {` loop before category heading and do ending table in same loop end.

Comment: Yes, i have done that, but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: What else i can do for that can help? Please let me know.

Comment: is there any way if we assign multiple categories to a product and the product is shown just once inside primary category? Currently if 2 or more categories are assigned to a product it appears under both categories on cart page. I will be very thankful if you can help.